# Nginx install wordpress under some URI prefix on existing website

Tags: wordpress, nginx

We have a website build with react by a partener. And we want to add a blog on the same domain, in a subdirectory:

- example.org => /var/www/example.org/app
- example.org/blog => /var/www/example.org/blog

I tried many solutions, but I always got a 404 on example.org/blog

```
server {

    server_name example.org;

    root /var/www/project/app/functions/build;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/example.org_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/example.org_error.log;

    index index.html index.htm;


    location ^~ /blog/ {
    
        access_log /var/log/nginx/blog-example.org_access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/blog-example.orgm_error.log;

        alias /var/www/example.org/blog;
        index /index.php;

        # Add a trailing slash if missing
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            rewrite [^/]$ $uri/ permanent;
        }
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location / {
       try_files $uri @prerender;
    }
    
    location @prerender {
        // .. config for react stuff
    }


    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

        fastcgi_index index.php;
        # Change this to your fpm socket
        fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

I tried to create a subdomain with a separate nginx site conf to test if everything was OK, and it was. So it's my nginx site config above which is not good.

Do you have any idea?
Thanks you!

**Solution**

Thanks to Ivan Shatsky, I was able to correct my config to make everything works.
My main issue why I always had a 404 was because of my index. I had an extra slash: `index /index.php` => `index index.php`

```
location /blog/ {

    access_log /var/log/nginx/blog-example.org_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/blog-example.org_error.log;


    root /var/www/example.org;
    index index.php;

    # Add a trailing slash if missing
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite [^/]$ $uri/ permanent;
    }

    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;
    

    location ~ \.php {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

        fastcgi_index index.php;
        # Change this to your fpm socket
        fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the final config. Missed that issue with the `index` directive, I said I'm not sure I found all the mistakes :) I'm about to bookmark this for the case if I ever need to do the same, can you rename your question to something like "Nginx install wordpress under some URI prefix on existing website"? It would be easier to find this when needed.

Comment: One more thing to mention. Although your particular case doesn't need it, if a solution like this would be applied to the configuration containing regex matching locations (`location ~ <regex> { ... }`), to prevent those locations capturing any of WordPress assets/routes, WordPress related location should be used with `^~` modifier: `location ^~ /blog/ { ... }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is an answer, but the errors I already see are:

- If your react app doesn't make use of PHP (and I suppose it doesn't) why do you use `location ^~ /blog/ { ... }` having a PHP handler below this block? This way, no request for `/blog/any/path/file.php` ever reaches that PHP handler. Use simple `location /blog/ { ... }` prefix location or move the PHP handler inside the `location ^~ /blog/ { ... }` making it nested location (preferred).
- If your directory where the WP is located is `/var/www/example.org/blog` and your URI pefix is `/blog/` you'd better use `root /var/www/example.org;` instead of `alias /var/www/example.org/blog;`. It those strings don't match, add the trailing slash at the end of the `alias` directive argument: `alias /var/www/example.org/blog/;`
- You are using `try_files` directive incorrectly, the last argument supposed to be a URI, so to redirect all the requests to WP index file, you should use `try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;`
- Your PHP handler uses global `/var/www/project/app/functions/build` root instead of WordPress one (if you'd make the PHP handler nested location, this one would be gone automatically).

Not sure that's all, but lets start from fixing these errors.

**Update**

The final working configuration was added by OP as the original question update.