# Can I use with nginx a domain name I already used with a wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress, nginx, hosting, digital-ocean

I own a domain name and I use it on my wordpress site

I build a little django web app which I deployed on DigitalOcean with nginx.

- my website looks like this : `https://<my_domain_name>.com`
  and
- my django app : `http:104.XXX.XXX.XXX` (just an IP for now)

What I want to have :

- Keep the same url for my wordpress website
- get this url for my django app : `https://<my_domain_name>.com/django_app`

Is there a way to do that ?
Can I build a ssl certificate even if I already use the domain_name somewhere else ?

I thought to install wordpress on my server and hosting my website and my django_app on the same server DigitalOcean (both with nginx), is it the solution ?

Comment: What about keeping the WP site at yourdomain.com and pointing a subdomain, like app.yourdomain.com, in your DNS records to the django app?

Comment: You can also do the /subfolder approach, it's definitely doable. I just don't know how to configure that in django.

Comment: ok so if I understand your method I need to buy a subdomain ? (app.yourdomain.com)

Comment: No! Or at least, I have never seen a subdomain being charged.

Comment: When you purchase your domain, it comes with the capability of creating any subdomain that you want off it

Comment: thank you very much :) that worked perfectly with subdomain and that's free you're right

Comment: Hey! Glad it worked :)

Comment: Somewhat late, but maybe could be useful too: [How to run Django and Wordpress using Nginx and Gunicorn at the same domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43067331/how-to-run-django-and-wordpress-using-nginx-and-gunicorn-at-the-same-domain), [Nginx install wordpress under some URI prefix on existing website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64670202/nginx-install-wordpress-under-some-uri-prefix-on-existing-website).